# Getting the connection string from appsettings.js inside service worker program

Tags: c#, sql-server, service-worker

Plenty of examples on how to do this with MVC and Startup.cs

How do I get the connection string from the appsettings.json inside the main program?

My code is full of crap.

```
namespace SetHospitalStatusToCurrentService
{
public class ConnectionConfig
{
    public string Analysis {get;set;}

}
}
```

Main program

```
namespace SetHospitalStatusToCurrentService
{
public class Program
{

    private SqlConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Analysis"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        return con;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        IServiceCollection services =  new ServiceCollection();
        //services.Configure<ConnectionConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.
            .ConnectionStrings["Analysis"].ToString();
        string sql = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM sso.Departments";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {            
            var departments = connection.Query(sql).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(departments.Count);
            
        }
        



    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {

                //services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); 

            });
}
 }
```

Going to be using Dapper

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if using .net core you need to use `IConfiguration` and not ConfigurationManager

```
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    // requires using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public TestModel(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public ContentResult OnGet()
    {
        var myKeyValue = Configuration["MyKey"];
       //Get Nested Element
        var title = Configuration["Position:Title"];
        var name = Configuration["Position:Name"];
        var defaultLogLevel = Configuration["Logging:LogLevel:Default"];


        return Content($"MyKey value: {myKeyValue} \n" +
                       $"Title: {title} \n" +
                       $"Name: {name} \n" +
                       $"Default Log Level: {defaultLogLevel}");
    }
}
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#default